# Regarding Events and Delegates in C#

Tags: c#, events, design-patterns, delegates

What are the side-effects of considering Events as instances of Delegates Type?

**Jon Skeet says, "Events aren't delegate instances.", [here.](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx).** I would not have asked this if I had read this anywhere else.

I had always, for the past 2 months, visualized Events as special type of Delegate with the **event** keyword just helping in preventing the nullification of the Delegate being invoked via the Event.

Could someone please elaborate on how to properly visualize the whole concept for someone new to C# and event based programming?

**EDIT 1:**

I understood the concepts of **delegates** and consequently **events** turned out to be a very simple concept. I would like to go ahead and add an example conjured by me during my battle with these constructs. I have added a lot of comments for better understanding. This is meant for new guys like me:

**THE LIBRARY DLL:**

```
namespace DoSomethingLibrary
{
    /*
     *This is a public delegate declared at the base namespace level for global presence.
     *The question is WHY do we need to have a DELEGATE here?
     *The answer is: I do not want to implement the LOGGING logic. Why? Well, my consumers are many
     *and all are equally demanding. They all need different types of logging. Some need HTML logging, 
     *some need XML logging for their custom log analyzer, some need plain text logging etc...
     *This is hell for me. How am I going to support all their demands. I cannot. Thus, I ask them to 
     *implement LOGGING on their side. I am providing an INTERFACE(literal sense) in the guise of a DELEGATE.
     *A DELEGATE is a HOOK.
     *This is the hook that is needed for consumers to hook their custom loggers into the library.
     */
    public delegate void Logger(string firstParam, string secondParam);

    public class PrintingManiac
    {
        public Logger printingManiacConsumerLoggerHook;
        public void StartPrintingLikeAManiac()
        {
            for (int iterator = 0; iterator <= 3; iterator++)
            {
                /*This loop is an emulator which I am using to emulate some huge processing or some huge job.
                 *Let us imagine that this is a library that does some heavy data crunching OR some 
                 *extremely complex data access job etc..
                 */
                Console.WriteLine("Actual WORK - " + iterator.ToString());
                /*After each step this library tries to LOG. But NOTE that this library
                 *has no LOGGER implemented. Instead, this library has judiciously DELEGATED
                 *the logging responsibilty to the CONSUMER of this library.
                 */
                printingManiacConsumerLoggerHook("Actual Work", "Step " + iterator.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**THE CONSUMER EXECUTABLE:**

```
/*
 * Let us assume that I have purchased the DoSomethingLibrary DLL from a vendor.
 * I have to add the DLL as a reference to my executable's project in Visual Studio.
 * I also have to use the DoSomethingLibrary namespace to access the Logic in the DLL.
 */
using DoSomethingLibrary;

namespace UnderstandingDelegates
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /*
             * Creating an object of the lone class PrintingManiac in the DoSomethingLibrary
             */
            PrintingManiac newManiac = new PrintingManiac();

            /*
             * HOOKING my custom logger to the DoSomethingLibrary DLL.
             * I get the best of both the worlds. I have a well-tested and efficient library working for me
             * AND I have the best logging avaliable.
             * The DoSomethingLibrary DLL has no knowledge of what logging this executable is going to use.
             * This executable has to just satisfy the requirements of the DELEGATE signature of DoSomethingLibrary DLL.
             */
            newManiac.printingManiacConsumerLoggerHook += new Logger(ClientsCustomizedLoggerTwo);

            newManiac.StartPrintingLikeAManiac();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void ClientsCustomizedLoggerOne(string firstParam, string secondParam)
        {
            /*
             *This logger has '=' used as a decorator
             *In real scenarios the logger may be very complex.
             *Let us assume this is an HTML logger
             */
            Console.WriteLine("=============================");
            Console.WriteLine("Delegated Logging IN CONSUMER code " + firstParam + " - " + secondParam);
            Console.WriteLine("=============================");
        }

        public static void ClientsCustomizedLoggerTwo(string firstParam, string secondParam)
        {
            /*
             *This logger has '-' used as a decorator
             *Let us assume this is an XML logger
             */
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Delegated Logging IN CONSUMER code " + firstParam + " - " + secondParam);
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------");
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

I have written an [article in CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/640971/Understanding-Delegates-in-Csharp-for-Beginners-Ba) to clearly explain the whole concept of delegates.

Comment: Jon elaborates on this just few lines further.

Comment: Events are backed by delegates but that is just an implementation detail - that doesn't make an event a delegate. You wouldn't say a property is a field (properties are backed by fields).

Comment: I am searching for different perspectives. Maybe some of your answers would give me the "AHA" moment:)
I am almost there, I feel. Just need the last push.

Comment: Events are events and delegates are delegates.

Comment: @KeesdeWit: So very precise for the ones who already know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how to properly visualize the whole concept

Nobody ever has much trouble visualizing *properties* in C#.  A property is an accessor to a *field*, it prevents other code from directly manipulating the field value.  Such code is forced to call the *get* and the *set* accessors to access the field.  You can put arbitrary code in the accessor methods, throwing an exception when you are not happy with the value passed to the setter for example, very common.  The underlying storage for the property doesn't have to be a field either, you can expose the field or property of another class object for example.  Etcetera.

A good way to visualize an *event* is to compare it to a property.  With the exact same intent, it prevents other code from directly manipulating a delegate object.  They have to go through the *add* and *remove* accessors.  The calls to these methods are generated by syntax sugar in the client code, the `+=` operator calls add(), `-=` calls remove().  Comparable to the syntax sugar for accessing properties, you don't explicitly write the call to the get or set method either.

What is confusing about events and makes them *seem* so different from properties is that the event accessor methods are **optional**.  If you don't write them then the C# compiler will auto-generate them for you.  Including the backing store, a delegate object.  Properties can also have auto-generated accessors and backing store, automatic properties do.  But the syntax is different, you still have to declare them.

Using the auto-generated accessors is *very* common.  That code is almost always good enough, it already provides the guarantee that arbitrary code cannot remove the event subscriptions of other code.  Not that many good reasons to write your own.  One is cutting down on the size of your class object if you support a lot of events.  Instead of having a delegate object for each individual event, you can store them in an EventHandlerList instead.  Very common in .NET framework code for example.  The extra indirection is also taken advantage of in WPF's attached events and WinRT's eventing model with isn't based on delegates.

Comment: Thank you Sir. All answers make sense to me now. But your answer made the concept crystal clear for me.

Comment: I think the reason events are more confusing that properties stems from C#'s (IMHO unfortunate) decision to have a declaration of event `foo` also declare by default a private delegate which is also named `foo`.  If declaration of event `foo` had declared a delegate named `foo_event` (the pattern in VB), and if an attempted invocation of `foo(whatever)` translated as `(foo_event ?? (x) => {})(whatever)`, there would IMHO have been much less confusion.  Too late now, though.

Answer (score 2):

An event consists of two special methods, called accessors, namely `add` and `remove`. Both take in one value parameter `value` of the same delegate type, and return `void`.

For example this is an event:

```
public event Action Exploded
{
  add
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Hello from 'add'. Type of 'value' is '{0}'.", value);
  }
  remove
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Hello from 'remove'. Type of 'value' is '{0}'.", value);
  }
}
```

A "field-like" event is a compiler-generated type of event where there is a private generated backing field of the delegate type in question, and where the `add` accessor adds `value` to the invocation list of that backing field (delegate combination) whereas the `remove` accessor removes `value` from that list. This is done in a smart thread-safe way.

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the biggest sources of confusion regarding events in C# stems from the fact that an event declaration which does not specify explicit add and remove methods creates a delegate with the same name as the event (a design I dislike, btw; VB.NET by default gives the delegate a different name).  Thus, declaring an event `foo` actually declares both an event named `foo` and a delegate named `foo`; the name `foo` will sometimes refer to the delegate and sometimes return to the event.

An event in .NET is really nothing more than a pair of methods, each of which accepts a delegate.  One of the methods is called "add", and should cause the method to cause the supplied delegate to be invoked if/when/whenever some particular condition arises.  The other method is called "remove", and should ask that a "subscription" associated with a particular delegate be cancelled.  Note that nothing about the general event contract requires that an event do anything with a passed-in delegate.  An immutable collection could implement an "observable collection" interface but simply ignore any requests to add or remove change notifications [the observable-collection contract would require that all delegates added to the "collection change" event be called when the collection changes, but since there would be no circumstance where the collection could actually change, there would be no circumstance where it would need to call the passed-in delegates].

By default, when a class one declares an event `eventName` in C#, the compiler also declares a variable `eventName` of the delegate type associate with the event.  Any statements of the form `eventName += someDelegate` will get translated as `eventName_add(someDelegate)` and statements of the form `eventName -= someDelegate` will get translated as `eventName_remove(someDelegate)`.  All other references to `eventName` will be regarded as references to the delegate of that name.  Note that in older versions of C#, if the delegate was in scope, statements of the `+=` and `-=` forms would operate directly on the delegate rather than on the event.  This meant that while subscription requests received from outside a class would go through add/remove methods (which would use locking or interlocked methods to provide thread-safety), those processed within a class would not be thread-safe.  Later versions of C# always regard `eventName += someDelegate` and `eventName -= someDelegate` as add/remove requests, however, even when the delegate is in scope.