# Regarding Syntactic Sugar

Tags: c#, syntax

What are the ways to identify Syntactic Sugar? For example, if someone is unaware of the version 1.0 of C# and gets involved in learning version 4.0, how should he/she go about detecting Syntactic Sugar? Is looking into the disassembled code the only way?

OR

Should a guy learning C# 4.0 go all the way down to 1.0, peeling one layer of abstraction after the other, to see the inner details?

An example:

When dealing with Events in C#, the following comes to my mind ([courtesy Hans Passan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162710/regarding-events-and-delegates-in-c-sharp)t)

> the += operator calls add(), -= calls remove()

P.S.

The questions I ask may be just too hilarious for the extremely knowledgeable crowd here. But making sense of the ever evolving software world is no "walk in the park". It is like finding your way out of the Amazon (I mean the Brazilian jungle. The website is easy to navigate.).

Comment: In regard to your first question, no! Syntactic sugar is find for someone new to a language. However, as you evolve, knowing what is syntactic sugar and what is not is important. How to spot it? Well, best I can suggest is to look it up! I don't think you need to disassemble to find it.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using syntactic sugar, generally speaking, but you should have an idea of what it's doing behind the scenes. For example, `i += 3;` is the same as `i = i + 3;`. Or, a bit less obvious, when you use `getters` and `setters`, the compiler generates a private backing field for you.

Comment: Sigh, I was typing a long answer when it got closed.  Rough summary: no, syntax sugar is a good thing for new programmers.  It makes the language much more accessible and helps them get the code right. But it certainly causes tooth decay for intermediary ones.  Getting past the sugar is the subject of *many* questions here.  Along with rather a lot of questions about a cavity.  As you can tell from what happened to your question, SO isn't the best place to find help taking the shortcut, cavities are on topic here.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I just wanted to know how people deal with a rapidly evolving language like c#. I am not trying to get help on the example I added in my question. I understand that quite well now. Thanks to you. What techniques people employ to peel one layer after the other of abstractions to get to the mechanics of the language is something that would be of great use. This is a general question aimed at extracting from the combined wisdom of the community, ways of dealing with complexity.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking about. Are you trying to reverse engineer some compiled C# code?

Comment: @Gilles: There are lots of syntactic abstractions added to C#. These are known as Syntactic Sugar in friendly terms. I am learning C# 4.0 and see a lot of sugar around. How to identify and deal with this stuff?

Answer (score 4):

Everything atop electric current is syntactic sugar for us humans. The computer doesn't need that nor does the alphabet or words as we know them mean anything to him.

Your job as a programmer is to use whatever feature makes you job easier. There is no bad feature if it makes you faster or better. Preferably both.

Answer (score 0):

You'll easily detect sugar going backwards from .NET 4.0 and noticing that simple "sugared" language structures from higher versions are getting more and more complicated.

Sugar is nothing bad, just need to know that there are many ways to accomplish certain task.